# Limit of an indefinite integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, indefinite-integrals

[image]

I need to prove that this limit exists and calculate it. I tried integration by parts, resulting with an integral which is called "The Cosine Integral", denoted $Ci(x)$. However, I need to deal with this question in a qualitative way, pretending as if I do not know the cosine integral or any other fancy function. I also tried to apply the so-called "Differentiability of the indefinite integral with variable endpoints", and I actually find the derivative function of the function for which I need to find the limit. But the derivative function is not defined at $x=0$, so I couldn't go that way either. Any suggestions?

Comment: The integrand looks like $1/t+\mathcal O(t)$ near $t=0$. Integrating we find the integral is $\log 3+\mathcal O(x^2)\to\log 3$ in the limit.

Answer (score 3):

*Too long for comments.*

For the limit itself, the problem is simple, as @Aaron Hendrickson did show in comments.

But we can go much further to get asymptotics and even more. Just write
$$\frac{\sin (t)}{t^2}=\frac 1t+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{ t^{2 n-1}}{(2 n+1)!} $$
$$\int_x^{3x}\frac{\sin (t)}{t^2}\,dt=\log(3)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n \frac{ \left(9^n-1\right) x^{2 n}}{2 n (2 n+1)!}$$

Computing the partial sums for $x=\frac \pi 6$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & \log(3)+\sum_{n=1}^p\\
 1 & 0.9158418368 \\
 2 & 0.9283687261 \\
 3 & 0.9278726579 \\
 4 & 0.9278854235 \\
 5 & 0.9278851944 \\
 6 & 0.9278851944 
\end{array}
\right)$$